# Is the sample independent from the mean?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, independence

I came across this question in Dobson's Introduction to Generalized Linear Models: [image]

What concerns me is that statement that the $\bar{Y}_j$ and $Y_{jk}$ are independent. How can $\bar{Y}_j$ (the sample mean for a particular group $j$) be independent with all the $Y_{jk}$ (all the observations in the sample)?

Comment: The sample mean and the samples are of course not independent. Maybe the intention is that means of different groups are independent, but it's hard to tell based on just this snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exercise is about an unpaired *t*-test (based on the instructions directly above the image). From a previous page:

> "Let $Y_jk$ denote the *k*th observation in the *j*th group where *j* = 1
> for the treatment group, *j* = 2 for the control group and *k* = 1, . . . , 20 for both groups." (p. 44)

So here, there are two $\overline{Y}_j$ one for each group. Because this is an independent *t*-test, the group means should be independent of one another. And each *j* is independent in this example, so the random *k* observations in group *j*=1 should be independent of the random *k* observations in group *j* = 2.